# Postgres update returning value giving string instead of json

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sql-update, psycopg2

I am attempting to update a json column in postgres (this is a bulk update using execut values). I am receiving a json object via an API. I insert the entire object into one column that is classified as a json column

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_data json NOT NULL default '{}'::JSON,
    createdt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

My update script looks like this:

```
UPDATE my_tableAS t
SET event_data = e.event_data::json
FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(id, event_data)
WHERE t.id= e.id
RETURNING *
```

I do a json.dumps on all json before hand

```
event_list.append([event['id'], json.dumps(event['data'])])
```

Once I get the completed rows I handle the data as such:

```
return json.loads(json.dumps(update_data, default=date_converter))
```

This all works properly when doing a straight insert into the json value, I dump the values before insert and then do the json.dumps/loads on the returning rows. Everything works fine. Just the update method.

Here is how the data is returned via the api on the update:

```
[
{
    "id": 170152,
    "event_data": "{\"commenttxt\": \"Test comment\", \"descrtxt\": \"HELLO WORLD\", \"eventcmpltflg\": false, \"eventcmpltontmflg\": false, \"active\": true}",
    "createdt": "2021-03-18T08:34:07Z"
}
]
```

And this is how I recieve it doing an insert:

```
[
{
    "id": 170152,
    "event_data": {
        "commenttxt": "Test comment",
        "descrtxt": "Test descr",
        "eventcmpltflg": false,
        "eventcmpltontmflg": false,
        "active": true
    },
    "createdt": "2021-03-18T08:34:07Z"
}
]
```

If I remove the json.dumps in the event_list.append section I get the error "Can't adapt type of dict".

For some context, I am not replacing individual elements inside the json. I am updating the entire column with a new set of json. I use a different table for tracking changes for historical/audit trails of what has changed. I use a json column because different teams use different values as their needs might be different so rather than using a table with a million columns to handle different teams json seemed best way to manage it.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. It turns out because I am just returning * that postgres is taking the already dumped values that I am inserting and returning that instead of returning from the table row directly. I had to modify the SQL accordingly

```
UPDATE my_table AS t
SET event_data = e.event_data::json
FROM (VALUES %s) AS e(id, event_data)
WHERE t.id= e.id
RETURNING t.*
```

So basically in my RETURNING i had to specify which table it came from and since i renamed my table as "t" it had to be t.* or if you want specific columns t.column_name.

I had assumed that it automatically return the data coming from the table and not the pseudo table created by the FROM statement.